# math game quiz with multiple answers

Tags: math, nsstring, uibutton, uilabel

I have a math quiz game and I want the user to be able to touch the buttons, right now it will only work if i have one button set as the right answer. Is it possible to make it a button combination like if the answer is 53 the user can touch the 5 button and 3 button.

ViewController.m

-(IBAction)EasyLevel:(id)sender {

```
Question.hidden = NO;
SelectLevel.hidden = YES;

buttonOne.hidden = YES;
buttonTwo.hidden = YES;
buttonThree.hidden = YES;
buttonFour.hidden = YES;
buttonFive.hidden = YES;
buttonSix.hidden = YES;
buttonSeven.hidden = YES;
buttonEight.hidden = YES;
buttonNine.hidden = YES;
buttonZero.hidden = YES;

Right1.hidden = YES;
Right2.hidden = YES;
Right3.hidden = YES;
Right4.hidden = YES;
Right5.hidden = YES;
Right6.hidden = YES;
Right7.hidden = YES;
Right8.hidden = YES;
Right9.hidden = YES;
Right0.hidden = YES;

Wrong1.hidden = YES;
Wrong2.hidden = YES;
Wrong3.hidden = YES;
Wrong4.hidden = YES;
Wrong5.hidden = YES;
Wrong6.hidden = YES;
Wrong7.hidden = YES;
Wrong8.hidden = YES;
Wrong9.hidden = YES;
Wrong0.hidden = YES;



int EasyQuestion = arc4random() % 2 ;
switch (EasyQuestion) {

    case 0:
        Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"What is 4 X 2"];
        Right1.hidden = NO;

        Wrong3.hidden = NO;
        Wrong4.hidden = NO;
        Wrong5.hidden = NO;
        Wrong6.hidden = NO;
        Wrong7.hidden = NO;
        Wrong8.hidden = NO;
        Wrong9.hidden = NO;
        Wrong0.hidden = NO;

        buttonOne.hidden =  NO;
        buttonTwo.hidden =  NO;
        buttonThree.hidden =  NO;
        buttonFour.hidden =  NO;
        buttonFive.hidden =  NO;
        buttonSix.hidden =  NO;
        buttonSeven.hidden =   NO;
        buttonEight.hidden =  NO;
        buttonNine.hidden =  NO;
        buttonZero.hidden =  NO;

        buttonOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"1"];
        buttonTwo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"2"];
        buttonThree.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"3"];
        buttonFour.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"4"];
        buttonFive.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"5"];
        buttonSix.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"6"];
        buttonSeven.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"7"];
        buttonEight.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"8"];
        buttonNine.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"9"];
        buttonZero.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"0"];
        break;

        case 1: .....
        default:
        break; }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks :) Stephanie

Comment: Have you considered using arrays and loops instead of writing the same thing ten times?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is how does the program know when the user is done entering digits by pressing buttons?

One approach might be to make the answer an editable text field (UITextField) and setting the focus to it and setting the keyboard to be the numbers type keyboard (via `UITextInputTraits` protocol which UITextField implements) so that the user can type in numeric vales.

If you don't want to use the iOS keyboard and just want your own custom buttons then you can use your own buttons and have the action for each button be to append the appropriate digit to the answer string which you might display in a UILabel and update as they press buttons.  You'd want to have a back/delete button so they can erase digits and update the string there also.  With this model you'd probably have an "ok" button or "done" button for them to indicate they are done and the current string is their answer.  That button would be the one that takes the string in the answer string at that point and checks it for correct/incorrect.

hopefully that's enough to get you going!